# FF keeps spinning after document.write()

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
       function fn() {
       document.write("Hello there!!!");
       }

    </script>
  </head>

   <body>
      <button onclick="fn()">click</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

After clicking the button , FF keeps on spinning (11.0), while as if I directly call the fn() without wiring it to the button , it works fine.Could anyone please look into this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to call [`document.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.close). `document.write` calls `document.open` if the document hasn't been opened. As long as the document isn't closed again with `document.close` the browser will indicate that the page is subject to change.

```
function fn() {
    // implicit call to `document.open();` before document.write
    document.write("Hello there!!!");
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ..But in the second case I mentioned , (where in i call fn directly (without clicking button) ,why it works fine , without calling document.close?

Comment: FF interprets the website top-down. When FF reaches the script, the document is still opened, and "Hello there" is going to be added to the document. After everything has been rendered, FF calls `document.close()` implicit. That's why the loading indicator fades away.

Comment: Then what exactly happens in the other case wherein I am clicking the button ?

Comment: Something like this will happen: Firefox renders page -> implicit call of `document.close()` -> you press the button -> implicit call of `document.open()` -> `document.write("Hello there!!!")`. The missing `document.close()` after `document.write()` results in spinning.

Comment: Reload stops working though, even when you call document.close() ... CMD + R doesn't work then.