# How to check server status with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I'm trying to write a script that allows me to check the *online* or *offline* status of servers. However, I currently have the problem that **Firefox** for some reason does not stop something to load when "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" set to *

The following code shows my previous status:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function() {

  urlList = ["example.com"]

  xhr = function(url) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          timeout: 3000,
          async: true,
          url: url
      }).done(function (data, statusText, xhr) {
          var status = xhr.status;
          var head = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders;
          console.log("getallresponseheaders");
          if (status === 200) {
              document.writeln(url + "     ------  is online");
          }
          console.log("status : " + status);
          console.log("head : " + head);
          console.log("url: " + url)
      }).fail(function ()
      {
          console.log(url + " ----- is offline");
      });
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
      xhr(urlList[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: You mean the server you're making a ajax request to sends a response header having "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" set to *?

Comment: @WarPro yes, thats right

Comment: And it works fine on Chrome?

Comment: Let us back up here. What do you really mean by "Firefox for some reason does not stop something to load when "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" set to *". Please elaborate/ provide more details so that we can help you better.

Comment: I mean that the loading bar in the "Tab" is active. It looks like it is waiting for a response. However, I can not find anything in the network activities.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with hooking code to 'pagebeforeshow' on FF.

Comment: currently i got the same problem without using 'pagebeforeshow'.
Do you have any other ideas about what the mistake could be?

Comment: Removing document.writeln(url + "     ------  is online"); fixes the issue.

Comment: wow, thank you! I have no Idea why, but it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call document.close(). document.write() internally calls document.open if the document hasn't been opened. As long as the document isn't closed again with document.close the browser will indicate that the page is subject to change and so keeps waiting.

This has been answered here ::: [FF keeps spinning after document.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595819/ff-keeps-spinning-after-document-write)

Comment: Keep rocking buddy!

Answer (score 0):

If server is in another domain then you need to do proper CORE request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: tenantBaseUri+"/RestRequest/GetLogisticsServerRestResponse",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true
}
```

And then on server side (you didn't mentioned what you are using for backend) you need to allow OPTIONS verb (Chrome and Firefox send that as preflight request before actual CORS request) and do other things to allow CORS (ex. in asp.net you may need add some CORS nuget packages like owin.cors or asp.net cors it depends)

Comment: He says it works on Chrome. And isn't preflight only for requests where authentication is involved?